# Query For BranchId From Current User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing a custom authorization and I have gotten the current user logged in but I want to check the current user branchid from `StaffBranch` model. This is the code.

```cs
if (BranchId != null)
{
    var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(context.User);
    var getuserstationid = _context.StaffBranch.Select(x => x.StationId);
}
```

I want to get the staffbranchid of the current user.

Comment: Can you share your `User` and `StaffBranch` models?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your mode design and how did you custom authorization,but you said you have got the current user.So you could find the current user id and then include the related model `StaffBranch` to get the `staffbranchid`.

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public StaffBranch StaffBranch { get; set; }
}
public class StaffBranch
{
    public int StaffBranchId { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public StaffBranch StaffBranch { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Get the staffbranchid:

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(context.User);
var BranchId = _context.Users
                        .Include(a => a.StaffBranch)
                        .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                        .Select(a => a.StaffBranch.StaffBranchId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```